# How to make links clickable in a QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, text, hyperlink, qtextedit, qtextbrowser

Is there a way to make links clickable in a [`QTextEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html)?

I know I can use a `QTextBrowser` and connect to `anchorClicked` but I'd rather keep the editing and viewing all in one widget, and have clickable links when I set the widget to read-only mode.

Is this possible or am I stuck with having two separate widgets  in a stack and switching between them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since [`QTextBrowser`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html) inherits from [`QTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html), you should use it and set the [`readOnly`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html#readOnly-prop) property to false. Then you can change the style of the QTextBrowser as you want.

Comment: I am missing something? Links in qTextBrowser turn to unclickable when ı set readonly to false.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to use text interaction flags. Now it works. Thank you